# How to use AWK for printing a line only if that line is different from the previous one?

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, genome

Very new into bioinformatics here!

I have a file that looks like this:

- gene-109.276      NC_014776.1     16296154
- gene-109.276      NC_014786.1     3209268
- gene-121.2    NC_014776.1     3335801
- gene-121.2    NC_014776.1     3345098
- gene-121.2    NC_014786.1     3337577

Where $1 is a gene, $2 is a match with a chromosome in another spp, $3 is the starting point of that match.
But I have too many hits. In order to graphic this I need to reduce the hits so I figured I´ll use just one match of a gene with the same chromosome with whatever value on col$3 (it doesn´t matter which value, but I do need that value).

I tried to use awk so that it prints the line only if $1 AND $2 are different from the previous one. But it is not working for me.
In this example the output should be:

- gene-109.276      NC_014776.1     16296154
- gene-109.276      NC_014786.1     3209268
- gene-121.2    NC_014776.1     3335801
- gene-121.2    NC_014786.1     3337577

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample input and output as text (code block) not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more simple way.

```
awk '$1$2!=n;{n=$1$2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to print each line if $1 OR $2 are different from the previous ones, rather than AND. For example:

```
awk '$1 != p1 || $2 != p2 { print; } { p1 = $1; p2 = $2; }'
```